# How to covert an C# array to unityscript

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to make an smartphone app with Unity3D and am using unityscript. I have bought some plugins from Prime31 and they all works fine, but the example script is written in C#.

I want to convert the example below into JS:

```
var buttons = new string[] { "Save", "Cancel" };
EtceteraBinding.showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons( "Alert!", "Do you want to save?", buttons );
```

I have tried like this:

```
var buttons:String[];
buttons=["Save","Cancel"];
EtceteraBinding.showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons( "Alert!", "Do you want to save?", buttons );
```

This is not good, course `["Save","Cancel"]` is showing in the first button and nothing in the other?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found your question on the forum of unity3d http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/145758-Setting-up-showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons-from-Prime31-in-js

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not using C#.  Prime's stuff isn't built for the abomination you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any documentation for `showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons()`?

Maybe in JavaScript the arguments are different. For example, maybe the button titles are passed as separate parameters instead of an array:

`showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons("Alert", "Something", "buttonTitle1", "buttontTitle2")`

Comment: yes, they could also be in object notation even. Best find the docs

Comment: // Shows a standard Apple alert with the given title, message and an array of buttons. At least one button must be included.

public static void showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons( string title, string message, string[] buttons )

Comment: That looks like the C# signature though, JavaScript might be different. Try it with separate parameters, or with object notation and see what happens.

Comment: There is no object notation.  We're not talking about web JS.  This is UnityScript.  Prime31 doesn't plan for it.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the doc you provided:

```
 // Shows a standard Apple alert with the given title, message and an array of buttons. At least one button must be included. 
 public static void showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons( string title, string message, string[] buttons )
```

You should just be able to use:

```
EtceteraBinding.showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons( "Alert!", "Do you want to save?", ["Save", "Cancel"]);
```

Comment: @Jesper Mansa Then either the docs are wrong or incomplete, or you have provided c# docs. As someone said in a comment, this is probably c# only. Can you demonstrate that the object EtceteraBinding is available to you by accessing the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have the Prime31 plugin and this compiles fine for me.

```
var test : String[] = ["One", "Two"];
EtceteraBinding.showAlertWithTitleMessageAndButtons("Name","Stuff", test);
```

If it doesn't work, what error are you getting in Unity?

Answer (score -2):

What about this:

```
var buttons = new Array("Save","Cancel");
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
var buttons = new Array();
buttons.push("Save");
buttons.push("Cancel");
```